# Rewriting statements without using any quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, solution-verification

Let $ P$ and $Q$ be predicates on the set $S$, where $S$ has three elements, say, $S = {a, b, c}$.
Then the statement $∀xP(x)$ can also be written in full detail as $P(a)∧P(b)∧P(c)$. Rewrite
each of the statements below in a similar fashion, using P, Q, and logical operators, but
without using quantifiers.

$(b) ∃xP(x)∧∃xQ(x)$ 
$(c) ∃x, y(P(x)∧Q(y))$ 
$(d) ∀x∃y(P(x) ∧ Q(y))$

I got the same answer for both part (b) and part (c) and (d), which is

$[P(a) ∨ P(b) ∨ P(c)] ∧ [Q(a) ∨ Q(b) ∨ Q(c)]$

... except it can't be the right answer for all of these statements, i believe. I'm not sure what I did wrong in coming up with these answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (c), think of the possible ways you can assign $(x,y)$ from the set $S$. $P(x) ∧ Q(y)$ must be true for at least one of those -- i.e. you can substitute each pair and join the expressions with a logical 'or'.

(d), from the rule you stated, can be rewritten $$\exists y (P(a) ∧ Q(y)) ∧ \exists y (P(b) ∧ Q(y)) ∧ \exists y (P(c) ∧ Q(y)).$$ From there, it shouldn't be too difficult to replace the $\exists$ with equivalent 'or' statements.